# Set accept-header with parameters in post-request

Tags: c#

I have a resource grabbed from my network-tools when using a web-app. From the header-section I got that:

[image]

Trying to translate that to code I wrote that:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(myUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.TryParseAdd("application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.TryParseAdd("api-version=5.0-preview.1");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.TryParseAdd("excludeUrls=true");
}
```

However when I debug that and see what's in `client.DefaultHeaders.Accept` it only contains the `application/json`-element. How can I combine all the information from within the image to the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple accept headers are separated by comma, not semi-colon. What you have there is actually just *one* type, with multiple parameters. Try this:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ParseAdd("application/json;api-version=5.0-preview.1;excludeUrls=true");
```

You should use `ParseAdd`, if you're not going to check the return value, so exceptions will be thrown. Then you would have noticed, that the 2nd and 3rd call throw.

Comment: I was pretty aware that the second and third throw. However the message didn't reveal any useful information to me except that the values could not be parsed. So the actual question came down to: how should we combine multiple accept-headers so that parsing works? Thank you for your answer. Works.